# $(a_n)_n$ is Cauchy iff $(\Re(a_n))_n$ and $(\Im(a_n))_n$ are Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, cauchy-sequences

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb C$. I want to show

> $(a_n)_n$ is Cauchy $\iff$ the real part $(\Re(a_n))_n$ and the imaginary part $(\Im(a_n))_n$ are both Cauchy

Comment: $|z| \le |\Re(z)| + |\Im(z)| $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MartinR's hint I solved it like this.

"$\implies$": Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Since $(a_n)_n$ is Cauchy, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$, such that for all $m,n \ge N$ we have $|a_m - a_n| \lt \varepsilon$. Then we have

$$|\Re(a_m)-\Re(a_n)| = |\Re(a_m - a_n)| \le |a_m - a_n| \lt \varepsilon$$

$$|\Im(a_m)-\Im(a_n)| = |\Im(a_m - a_n)| \le |a_m - a_n| \lt \varepsilon$$

because $|\Re(z)| \le |z|$ and $|\Im(z)| \le |z|$. Therefore $(\Re(a_n))_n$ and $(\Im(a_n))_n$ are both Cauchy sequences.

"$\impliedby$": Let $\varepsilon \gt 0$. Since $(\Re(a_n))_n$ is Cauchy, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb N$, such that for all $m,n \ge N_1$ we have $|\Re(a_m) - \Re(a_n)| \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since $(\Im(a_n))_n$ is Cauchy, there exists $N_2 \in \mathbb N$, such that for all $m,n \ge N_2$ we have $|\Im(a_m) - \Im(a_n)| \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Let $N := \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then for all $n \ge N$

$$\begin{align} |a_m - a_n| &\le |\Re(a_m - a_n)| + |\Im(a_m - a_n)| \\ &= |\Re(a_m) - \Re(a_n)| + |\Im(a_m) - \Im(a_n)| \\ &\lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon \end{align}$$

since $|z| = \sqrt{\Re(z)^2 + \Im(z)^2} \le \sqrt{\Re(z)^2} + \sqrt{\Im(z)^2} = |\Re(z)| + |\Im(z)|$. Therefore $(a_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, any finite collection of Cauchy sequences is also a Cauchy sequence and the reason is exactly what you said, but a little preciser. First you must define a metric on any singleton Cauchy sequence (since metrics are equivalent it doesn't matter which to choose) then combining them together to derive a general metric, i.e. assume a long-term sequence has been defined as $a_{n}=(a_{1,n},a_{2,n},...,a_{k,n})$ for some k. Define then a unique metric d(x,y) on the metric space in which $a_{i,n}$s are defined (for example R). Taking on general metric $d_{total}(x,y)=\sqrt {d(x_{1},y_{1})^{2}+d(x_{2},y_{2})^{2}+...+d(x_{k},y_{k})^{2}}$ (or whatever metric you want for example on $R^{k}$) and using triangle inequality the expected result could easily be concluded.